# Run an individual test parameter in junit 5

Tags: junit5

Lets say I have a parameterized test like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"a", "B", "r"})
void test1(String val) {
   assertNotNull(val);
}
```

What I'd like to do is just run the test for one value. Is there a way to do it? I know how to run an individual test, but if there's a notation to run just the one parameter, that would be of help. Looking to run it through Maven.

Comment: Where do you want to run it? In your IDE, with Gradle or Maven? Under the good Jupiter has a mechanism to do it but support for it varies from tool to tool.

Comment: @johanneslink I updated the description; I'm running it in Maven

Comment: I'm not a Maven user myself. so I checked https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html. It looks like running a single TestIdentifier (Jupiter's way to address individual paramterized test cases) is currently not being supported. You might want to open a feature request for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, you can specify the "**uniqueId**" parameter as a test run parameter.

You can extract the id (which is a very complicated string) as follows.

Run the test as usual, so Eclipse will show each single run in the JUnit panel as a tree.

Select a single run and execute it in debug mode, place a breakpoint whereever you want.

Click on the *Properties* menu in the Debug perspective:

[image: properties menu]

Copy the uniqueId parameter from the Command Line window:

[image]

And add it as a command line parameter in your JUnit Run configuration:

[image]

Comment: Not using Eclipse. Like it says in the description, using Maven

Comment: even though it's eclipse-related - thanks for providing one of the very few examples one can find on how to use this feature of the test runner!